# How can we combine "cases" of solutions to equations (eg, $\sin x=\sin\theta$) as a unified "$x=\cdots$" statement?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Suppose we were to solve the equation:$$\sin x=\sin \theta$$
After solving we obtain the following solutions:
$$
\left\{ 
\begin{aligned}
x&=\theta +2k\pi \\ \mathbf {or}\\
x&=\pi -\theta + 2k\pi
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$
How do you rewrite the solutions using only one equation? In our particular case, we can write:
$$x=k\pi + (-1)^k\theta
$$
for every integer $k$.

How would you derive this? I need a method capable of uniting any set of equations with some solutions into one equation with the same solutions.

Comment: Can sb tell me what to google for to find some answer? I'm not sure of the name of what I am trying to achieve. What is this process called in technical terms? It's nowhere like solving a system of equations because of the "OR" operator in between equations which prohibits us from using most of equivalence properties.

Answer (score 3):

Usually not, but here there is a simplification. Note the second equation implies
$$
x = -\theta + (2k+1)\pi
$$
and the first one is $x = \theta + 2k\pi$. To unite them, note that the difference is in the parity of the coefficient of $\pi$ and the sign of $\theta$, and since $(-1)^{2k+1} = -1$ this solves your problems, you just claim that $$x = (-1)^n \theta + n\pi$$ and then when $n$ is even it's like your first equation and when $n$ is odd, it is your second equation...

Comment: Thanks. That was a nice derivation. So, there is no general way for uniting equations which are explicitly solved for, and only need a more general formula? I really like doing math using logic. The logical operator between the equations is "OR" which corresponds to set union. If it was "AND", then it meant intersection of solution sets and we could use the very nice properties of equality operator which allows substituting one equation into another. I wonder if we could use De Morgan's law to turn "OR" into "AND" but I don't know what to do with the inequations I get from the process.